# Why do we need IPSec VPN rather than SSL?

Tags: ssl, ip, vpn

IPSec VPN is security provided at Network layer with following facilities:

```
Authentication

Data Integrity

Confidentiality

Anti-Replay
```

But making this set up is more costlier than using `SSL` at `Application layer`.

For example: http uses SSL to talk to Web server

So, Why people use VPN?

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much gave the answer yourself: encryption on the network layer provides security for ***all*** traffic that goes through it, instead of each application having to implement its own security model.

VPNs are also used in completely different scenarios than your typical HTTP request. You most typically use VPNs to join into an intranet from outside and use all the network internal services. Doing this via a VPN means you just need to expose one network entry point to the outside world. Otherwise you'd have to expose every single service to the outside world, *and* implement individual security models for each.

Comment: Do you think, mobile phone client that use http browsers prefer ssl at application layer? using VPNs from mobile phones would be too much to ask?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the browser "prefers". It matters whether the browser can access whatever service it's trying to access in the first place. Again, VPNs are typically used to dial into intranets. It doesn't matter whether some intranet web service is served over SSL or not if it's hidden inside an intranet that you *need* a VPN connection to.

Comment: But in my company, in addition to dialing to intranets from home(laptop), we also have VPN setups configured over multiple routers through dedicated interfaces, What kind of VPNs are these? Why do we need such setup?

Comment: I don't know why *you* in particular need that setup. Ask your network gurus. My guess would be because you're trying to bridge two private intranets, communication between which is routed through the public internet.

Comment: Yes you are right, we are bridging two private intranets thru internet. Is this called MPLS VPN or something else?

Comment: I don't know what MPLS is in particular, but it seems to be one sort of VPN. I don't know how this relates to your situation in particular. You really are on the wrong site here, these questions have nothing to do with programming. Try http://serverfault.com, but better make sure you have a really concrete question before you post there.